# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. - Cdyne Postback

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, ssl, https

I am having a website (PHP/MySQL). Recently I upgraded the server and installed SSL certificate to my website (server).
Server and SSL details are

**HTTP Server Header:** Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.5.29

**Protocol (supported):** TLS 1.2

**Protocol (NOT supported):** TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, SSL 3, SSL 2

I am using Cdyne SMS Notify API in my website. Cdyne posts back (to a page I have specified in Cdyne call) after completing process at their end when I send request to them.

Without SSL (https) everything works good and I get back post backs (to a page I have specified in Cdyne call) from Cdyne but when I enable SSL (https) then I don't get posts back. I contacted with Cdyne support, they replied that they are getting following exception when they try to send reply (post back) to my website.

**The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**

What can be the reason? And what can be the solution. Do I need to change my code or do they will have to alter their code. Any help is appreciated.

**Last but not least,** requests (SMS) from my website are successfully delivered with SSL (https). Means everything is good at my end? Issue is only with post backs from Cdyne.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Cdyne's implementation which was not allowing posting back to TLS 1.2 server. After they fixed the code at their end everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

CDYNE recently performed a security upgrade. It also required a patch to our previous version.

This upgrade was to ensure that all of our customers, from legacy to current versions, have the highest level of encryption for their data. There was a minor interruption while this transition occurred and isn't a regular occurrence with our services.

If you experience any issues in the future, you can always chat with us online through [our website](http://www.cdyne.com) or call our tech support line at 1-800-984-3710.

Comment: Thank You! The issue has been fixed. :) Please check my own comment which I accepted as answer.